# Property 'condition' does not exist on type '{}' object

Tags: typescript

i was facing issue while adding key and value in object but am getting error like   Property 'condition' does not exist on type '{}' object.

```
static deleteProductReview(request: Request) {
    let deleteParam  = { };
    deleteParam['condition']={'name': "ssssss"},
    deleteParam['params']={
        'reviews_ratings': {
            'regno': "468sdsdd")
        }
    };
    return deleteParam;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
 {
        condition:{
            name: ssssss
        },
        params:{
            reviews_ratings:{
                regno:468sdsdd
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `deleteParam.condition`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to immediatelly assign value where typescript will infer object type

```
static deleteProductReview(request: Request) {
    let deleteParam = { 
      condition: { name : "ssssss" },
      params: {
        reviews_rating: {
          regno: "468sdsdd"
        }
      }
    };
    return deleteParam;
}
```

If you are going to add properties dynamically under specific conditions, and you don't want to define specific type for `deleteParam`, you can just mark it as `any`

```
static deleteDynamicProductReview(request: Request) {
    let deleteParam: any = { };
    deleteParam['condition']={'name': "ssssss"},
    deleteParam['params']={
        'reviews_ratings': {
            'regno': "468sdsdd")
        }
    };
    return deleteParam;
}
```

Please note that you won't have autocomplete on object returned from `deleteDynamicProductReview` since it will be of type `any`.